# Safe Directory Delete

Tags: bash, shell, rm

I alias `rm` to `rm -i` so that when I mistype `file*` as `file *` I get prompted before accidentally deleting files I didn't intend to delete.  Is there an equivalent idiom for directories?

In particular, to delete a directory and its contents, you have to `rm -r`.  Using `rm -ri` will prompt you for all the files in it, not just the top-level directory.  For directories with a lot of files, that's not convenient. To avoid that, I frequently use `rm -rf`, but that scares me.  I'm only a typo away from blowing away lots of important stuff (e.g. `rm -rf ~ /foo` instead of `rm -rf ~/foo`—ouch!).

One could write a mildly annoying script to replace, e.g., rmdir with something that only prompts for the things listed on the command line, but it seems like this is the kind of problem for which a solution should already exist.

Comment: If would personally never do `rm -rf ~/foo`, but by default `cd ~; rm -rf foo/` I think it is mostly a matter of good habbits.

Comment: I like that.  Good advice for that one case.  But the problem still exists.  For example 'rm -rf *_old'.  What if you mistype 'rm -rf * _old'?

Comment: @Bernhard except you want `&&` instead of `;`, otherwise you way delete the wrong directory if the `cd` fails for some reason.

Comment: @jordanm I'd normally not type them on a single line obviously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rm -i` would get extremely annoying especially when removing recursively.

`rm -I`, on the other hand seems a little more tolerable which will prompt **once** before removing **more** than **three** files, **or** when removing **recursively**.

It's **much** less intrusive while still giving protection against *most* mistakes.

The *best* form of protection is to double/triple check when deleting recursively or better yet, *anything* you delete.

Comment: In my experience, this kind of aliases just makes the "rm foo<ENTER>y<ENTER>" automatic... i.e., _no_ protection at the cost of 2 extra keystrokes. And it isn't available everywhere. Better don't do that, except for the greenest training-wheel-needy users.

Comment: Seeing that `rm foo` would only remove one file. `rm foo` would only ask once. If you're talking about when removing the directory foo/ then the command `rm -Ir foo` would ask once as well _(if it contained more than 3 files)_. If you were to remove a directory recursively that had 1000 files in it (for arguments sake). Then you'd be there for quite a bit of time saying `Yes` to confirm __all__ the files with `-i` where since the user should know what files their deleting `-I` will ask once for any removal operation with __three or more__ files involved.

Comment: Adding to that. If the user doesn't know what's contained in `foo/` then when `rm -Ir foo` is passed and it asks "You sure?" and the user says `Yes` without double checking __and__ not knowing what's in the directory. Then, that's something nobody can answer other than. "Pay attention to what _you're_ doing to _you're_ system. Or go back to using the Recycle Bin in Windows."

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a trash can approach, like [here](http://hashbang.net/2009/03/trash-with-bash/).
There are a lot of examples out there besides this one - it was just the first in my search results. Basically, all rm operations become mv commands. If you rm the wrong files, they're still on the machine and easily recoverable. And the approach linked above creates an alias to the base rm command so you can still use it when you really want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can cd to the top level directory you want to remove recursively, then go up a level and rm that directory. That way you don't have to use leading slashes, etc.

```
cd /home/user/junk
ls -1

folders
to
delete

rm -ri . ###Or "rm -rf ."
cd ..
rm -rf junk
```

Another way to check that your paths are right for any command is to simply use tab completion.